# MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE crashes app when playing recorded video from preview screen on Noughat devices

Tags: android, video-capture

I am recording video using default camera using intent however, as soon as video is recorded preview screen is shown. I have not created preview screen. This is default screen of Android. On clicking play button, app is crashing without any error.

Below is the code:

```
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

 videoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,30);                    
 videoIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);

startActivityForResult(videoIntent,REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

No error is showing in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

> as soon as video is recorded preview screen is shown. I have not created preview screen. This is default screen of Android

Based on your code, that would be part of the camera app that you happen to be using.

> On clicking play button, app is crashing without any error.

Apparently that particular camera app has a bug. This is not surprising.

Bear in mind that there are dozens of different camera apps that might respond to your `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` `Intent`, and that they are not required to pay attention to your `android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA` extra, as that is not part of [the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` protocol](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).